Long.MaxValue conversion from Single to Long causing Overflow exception
The value of Long.MaxValue is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. When cast to a single precision value, becomes 9.223372E18. However the cast back to a Long throws a System.OverflowException. This despite the fact that the value in the Single is actually less than the possible maximum value of the long. Experimentation in the watch window shows that in fact the value
8.070450532247929344e18

is the largest double precision value that will safely ctype to a Long. Try this in the watch window:
CType(8.070450532247929344000001e18, Long)

further
8.070450807125836288e18

is the largest double precision value that after conversion to single precision, will safely convert to a Long, using this statement in the watch window:
CType(CType(8.0704508071258362880000001e18, Single), Long)

This seems like very strange behaviour.
Why?
Edit: Further Experimentation
The above experimentation is using the watch window and CTypes. Another experiment yields another answer:
Dim d As Long = 200000000000
Dim delta As Long = d / 2
Dim c As Long
Dim a As Single
Dim b As Long
While delta > 0
    c = Long.MaxValue - d
    a = c
    Try
        b = a
        delta = delta \ 2

        d = d - delta
    Catch ex As Exception
        d = d + delta

    End Try
End While

The above code yields the largest Long that can be cast back and forth is:
9,223,371,761,976,868,860

or
Long.MaxValue - 274,877,906,947


Floating points loose precision so likely it’s overflowed the long

@J Collins: Please clarify what you mean by "safely convert to a Long".

When debugging, ctype(ctype(8.070450807125836288000000e18, single), long) and ctype(8.07045053224792934400000e18, Long) are the largest values that will not throw an exception or error.

Does this answer your question? Which is the first integer that an IEEE 754 float is incapable of representing exactly?

Unusual question. Are you using MaxValue as a "magic number" ?

@Charlieface no this is much more peculiar behaviour than that. I'm continuing to add to the question as I learn more.

@SSS I am using MaValue as a scaling parameter to maximise the integer resolution of a data stream of known limits, for later high-speed processing.

As in the answer: "The maximum possible integer you can safely store in a floating point number is 2^24 for a float and 2^53 for a double" so the value is being rounded. It's essentially the same thing, there is no further weirdness.

That is the largest integer before skipping of whole integers occurs, it doesn't speak to the largest integer that can be represented by the float and safely exchanged back and forth, which is significantly lower than MaxValue - 1, and different depending on how it is approached.


When cast to a single precision value, Long.MaxValue becomes 9.223372E18, which is less than the possible maximum value of the Long.

Although 9.223372E18 is the default string representation of the result, this is misleading. The exact result is not 9.223372 × 1018 but rather 263 = 9,223,372,036,854,775,808, which is the closest possible Single to the original value of 263 − 1. (The difference of 1 is due to the inability of Single to precisely represent the original value.)
Because 263 exceeds Long.MaxValue, attempting to cast it back to a Long throws OverflowException.
What is the largest Long that can be represented exactly by a Single?
We want to find the maximum possible value of L = 2e × s < 263, where the integer exponent e satisfies −126 ≤ e ≤ 127, and the significand s = (1.b22b21...b0)2 consists of the binary digit 1 followed by 23 fractional binary digits.

If e ≥ 63, then L ≥ 263, which is too large. So e = 62.
The maximum possible s is (1.11...1)2 = 2 − 2−23.

Thus L = 262 × (2 − 2−23) = 263 − 239 = 9,223,371,487,098,961,920.
What is the largest Long that can be converted to a Single and back to a Long without overflowing?
The answer M is the midpoint of L (from above) and Long.MaxValue:
M = (L + 263 − 1) \ 2 = 263 − 238 − 1 = 9,223,371,761,976,868,863.
When you convert any Long between L and M to a Single, you get L:
Dim a As Long = 9223371761976868863
Dim b As Single = a
Dim c As Long = CType(b, Long)
Console.WriteLine(c) ' Output: 9223371487098961920

When you convert any Long between M + 1 and Long.MaxValue to a Single, you get 263, which exceeds Long.MaxValue.
Why does CType(8.07045053224793E+18, Long) fail to compile?
Good question. A Double should be convertible to a Long at compile time if its value is within the range of the Long data type (approximately ±9.223E+18). 8.07045053224793E+18 is less than Long.MaxValue, and in fact the conversion succeeds at run time:
' This code generates error BC30439: Constant expression not representable in type 'Long'.
Const a = 8.07045053224793E+18
Const b As Long = CType(a, Long)

' But the identical code with Dim instead of Const compiles successfully.
Dim a = 8.07045053224793E+18
Dim b As Long = CType(a, Long)
Console.WriteLine(b) ' Output: 8070450532247929856

Therefore, this is clearly a bug in VB.NET’s compile-time conversion logic. Indeed, I traced the bug to the following decade-old block of code within the compiler, which is supposed to check whether the sourceValue is between &H7000000000000000L and &H8000000000000000UL, and if so, return False to indicate "no overflow":
If sourceValue > &H7000000000000000L Then
    Dim temporary As Double = (sourceValue - &H7000000000000000L)

    If temporary < &H7000000000000000L AndAlso UncheckedCLng(temporary) > &H1000000000000000L Then
        Return False
    End If
Else

But the developer incorrectly used > instead of < in the comparison UncheckedCLng(temporary) > &H1000000000000000L. I’ve submitted a pull request to get this corrected.
The usage of the somewhat arbitrary constant &H7000000000000000L in this code explains the strange behavior you observed: converted to a Double, this constant equals 8.0704505322479288E+18.

This is a great answer, and adds to a long list of VB specific IDE/compiler bugs I've come across in Visual Studio. I think the mathematical answer to the max value seems exactly right, though the result deviates by 3 from the experimentally derived figure. As it turns out the whole exercise has been made moot by my discovery that integer division is so slow as to swamp any other benefits in general purpose calculation, so am now promoting all incoming types to doubles.

Your question is essentially "why do some integers not round trip when converted to floating points and back to integers?" Well, because of precision issues inherent in the IEEE 754 format that .NET uses for its floats.
If you run this code (it's C#, but it works the same in VB.NET or in any of .NET's supported languages):
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine((ulong)long.MaxValue);
        Console.WriteLine((ulong)(float)long.MaxValue);
    }
}

You end up with
9223372036854775807
9223372036854775808

Notice how the second number is off by one. How is this possible?
The maximum possible integer you can safely store in a floating point number is 2^24 for a float and 2^53 for a double (i.e. the number of bits in their mantissa, plus 1 for the sign bit). That's the maximum precision you can get. Larger numbers cannot be accurately represented, so you get an approximation instead. In fact, according to the Wikipedia article on the subject:

Integers between 2^n and 2^(n+1) round to a multiple of 2^(n-23)

long.MaxValue is too large (it's 2^63-1), so it's not stored exactly. It's instead rounded up to a multiple of 2^39, which is 2^63. And that's too big to fit in a long, so you'll get an exception in a checked context.
If you put in 9223372036854775807 in a tool like this one, you'll see the value actually being stored is 9223372036854775808. Just as expected.
If that's really a problem, you can use decimal, which is a quad-precision number and can safely fit integers of up to 2^113-1:
// This Just Works (tm)
Console.WriteLine((long)(decimal)long.MaxValue);

Or you could just not use floating point numbers.
Floating point numbers aren't broken, they're just built different.

I like the thought that the off by one is a root cause, but fresh experimentation shows the difference to be much larger in representable values.

It's not off by one in the sense of the ones digit, it's a question of the precision in the mantissa in the floating point format.  Once you go over 2^24 in single precision, representation will start skipping values, and the length of the skip will increase as you go higher.  Bruce Dawson's blog article here discusses the value skipping better than I can in a comment: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2020/09/27/floating-point-in-the-browser-part-1-impossible-expectations/  I do note that this doesn't address the max value you presented in the question.
